# windows 7 cannot shutdown after wake up from sleep S3

Tags: windows-7, sleep, shutdown, wake-up

I have a clean install Windows 7 SP1 x64,BIOS is Load Optimized Defaults,only change SATA IDE to AHCI.when I sleep and wake up,then I shutdown,Windows 7 stuck at shut down,but doesn't turn off monitor and system.However if I shutdown without sleep and wake up before,shutdown works well.How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This particular issue relatively depends on drivers, that could cause this issue. Please update device drivers including chipset driver, mouse driver and display card driver. You can check and list the devices which may cause this issue using the below command:

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_from_any
```

Please try update the device drivers and check the outcome.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much,I use Driver Booster 2 to update all my drivers,and now sleep wake up and shutdown works well.